# How to restrict the URL length in nginx ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, url-validation

I have an application is accessible from url: `hw.internal.com/api/apple`.

Now I want to restrict the length of the url that can be fired to 26 characters.
That is if i try to call `hw.internal.com/api/watermelons` 
it should give 414 error as the url length exceeded 26 characters.

I found that I could use the following code lines in Ingress by which I could restrict the url length to 26 characters.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      if ($request_uri ~* "^/.{26,}") {
        return 414;
      }
```

However I want to know if there are there any annotations available for ingress that would help me achieve this.

Comment: The solution you have found using a server snippet is a valid approach. As far as I know there isn't a specific annotation in Nginx ingress to limit the URL length.